# REST server response to authorization

Tags: http, rest, basic-authentication

I have a question about REST. I´m creating a service, in which the client sends HTTP request with Basic authorization (Header `Authorization: Basic user:password`). I want the server to control user credentials, and if they are correct, it would send `200 OK`, otherwise `401 Unauthorized`. If the credentials are OK, I want to send back also user´s ID. My question is, what would be the best way to send that? My options are: headers, or json in the body of the response. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would send it back in the body. I don't think there are any standard headers suitable for that type of information, unless you are setting it in a cookie.

Comment: Yes, that´s the problem, I haven´t found any suitable header too. Thanks.

Comment: And the `Cookie` header isn't very RESTful - I wouldn't use that in a REST API. There's not much of an advantage to having it a response header - maybe it's arguably cleaner if you want to return it with every response, but non-standard headers run the risk of being stripped by proxies and CDNs, so I think I'd also go for the body.